# I am getting an error for a basic opencv code to load and show a image

Tags: python, image, opencv, artificial-intelligence

code:

```
import cv2

import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('test1.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

cv2.imshow('image',img)

cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\python file", line 6, in 
cv2.imshow('image',img)

cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-h4wtvo23\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

Comment: There is not an image called `test1.jpg` in the directory in which your program is running.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your the path to the image does not exist or is corrupted (empty). Probably the former. Make sure you set the correct path to the image `test1.jpg` either by making sure that the path is set correctly from the directory you are running the program from, or using the absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem when working with opencv in c++, the problem was solved when I used the full path to both the model and the image. Do this to make sure that the path is indeed the problem.
If so, I recommend using pathlib package to manage paths in your code, it'll help avoid path issues in the future.